# new remote head on branch? mercurial push error

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I created a branch and made some changes.  The branch was abandoned/closed as the changes didn't work and the branch was created from the wrong revision.

I then created another branch with the same name.  It appeared to work.
But when I tried to commit the working code to the branch I get an error.

```
abort: push creates new remote head d5d16a77e4a2 on branch 'EP-4258'!
hint: merge or see 'hg help push' for details about pushing new heads
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/2591276/1256452 (different question but mentions what the complaint means)

Comment: The question is,  what is a remote head?

Comment: A *head* in Mercurial is a commit with no descendants on the same branch. See `hg help heads`. A head isn't really local or remote, it's just a commit / revision that meets this constraint, but the phrase *remote head* means *the other Mercurial, the one that's receiving the push, made this calculation using the revisions **it** has or would have*. You don't necessarily have the same revisions yet: you have to `hg pull` to get any revs they have, that you don't.

Answer (score -1):

> branch was abandoned/closed

Error 1

> created another branch with the same name

Error 2

> How do I fix this?

Grok `hg heads`, "... merge or see 'hg help push' for details about pushing new heads"

Comment: In the end I checked out the project again.  Created a new branch with a new name and added the changes back.  Sorted! Thanks